# razor asks for ; when doing using(Html.BeginForm())

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
Name:
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Name)
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
```

this gives error **CS1002: ; expected**

it works if I remove the **Name:**

or if I do it like this:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("AddHuman")" method="post">
Name:
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Name)
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is most likely with your `Name:` literal.  Since you are inside a code block, Razor assumes that the next lines are code lines.  You can escape this with either prepending `Name:` with `@:` or by wrapping it with `<text></text>`.  The text tag is special for Razor and will be removed when it is parsed by the view engine.

The reason your `<input>` will be fine is that Razor recognizes that it is a markup tag and will write it out to the response stream, with `Name:` it can't assume that since it isn't an actual markup tag.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes razor gets confused, so you will need to wrap your code inside of a html tag. In case you do not wish to add additional html tags just because razor doesn't gets it, you can use `<text>` which will be removed.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
   <text>
       Name:
       @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Name)
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </text>
}
```

Comment: You can also do @@Name: