# passing multiple parameters in @html.actionlink()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, actionlink

I'm using actionlink to pass parameter "code" to controller for an item and get details for that item on new view (actually, it's controller that calls 3 partial views)

I also need to pass parameter "description" but that's just an value that need to be shown as  on new view and has no use in controller (i'm using "code" to filter database records).

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyModel)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink(item.code, "Index", "ControlerName", new { pos = item.code.ToString(), desc = item.desc.ToString() }, null)
</td>
```

}

this actionlink give me url /ControlerName?pos=code&desc=desc

Is there a way to send "desc" parameter so it won't be seen in url but only shown as  in new view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Html.ActionLink only exists to generate a url and plop it inside an anchor tag. You should be repopulating the desc value from your Index action when it's hit.

Answer (score 9):

You have to pass the parameter like you have it so that the other controller and view is aware of the data that's being persisted.

An alternative would be to store your description in a "lookup table" that you can identify by `id`, so you only need to pass the `id` and it will be the `Controller's` or `ViewModel's` responsibility to look that up.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.code, "Index", "ControllerName", new { id=1 }, null)
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id) {
    // Go to DB and get the description by id.
}
```

Comment: My response was marked as the answer, but yours was the better response!

Answer (score -2):

Use form tag and pass all parameters you want to the actionresult and return any other actionresult(which will carry your desired url with it) you want.

[razor asks for ; when doing using(Html.BeginForm())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713931/razor-asks-for-when-doing-usinghtml-beginform)

Comment: I would love to hear what other way u can pass the parameter without including it in the url! Since you down voted it, could you please answer it or put a comment to clarify the reason?