# Wrong hidden filed value is being passed to the Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Update :**

This is an SPA app.So it's having js file also for supporting the submit button.So I think problem is on it.Could you tell me how to modify it to support multiple kind of submit buttons ? At this moment I think it supports only for a single submit button.That is why it always get the first form's hidden field value I think.Thanks.

**JS**

```
 var $loginForm = $('.login-form');

 $loginForm.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (!$('.login-form').valid()) {
                return;
            }

            abp.ui.setBusy(
                null,
                abp.ajax({
                    contentType: app.consts.contentTypes.formUrlencoded,
                    url: $loginForm.attr('action'),
                    data: $loginForm.serialize()
                })
            );
        });
```

**UI**

[image]

**VM**

```
 public class LoginViewModel
    {
        public string TenancyName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UsernameOrEmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

**CompanyLoginFormViewModel VM :**

```
 public class CompanyLoginFormViewModel
    {
        public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }

        public List<TenantListDto> Tenants { get; set; }

    }
```

***.cshtml page**

```
@{
    var companyLoginFormViewModel = TempData["CompanyLoginFormViewModel"] as CompanyLoginFormViewModel;
} 

    @foreach (var tenant in companyLoginFormViewModel.Tenants)
                {
                    <form class="login-form" action="@Url.Action("Login")?returnUrl=@ViewBag.ReturnUrl" name="companyLoginForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="usernameOrEmailAddress" value="@companyLoginFormViewModel.LoginViewModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress" />
                <input type="hidden" name="password" value="@companyLoginFormViewModel.LoginViewModel.Password" />
                       <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="true" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="companyUrl" value="true" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="tenancyName" value="@tenant.TenancyName" />

                        <div class="row margin-top-10">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase">@L("LogIn")</button>
                            </div>
                           </div>
                    </form>
                }
```

***Generated html***

```
     <form class="login-form" action="/Account/Login?returnUrl=/Application" name="companyLoginForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
         <input type="hidden" name="usernameOrEmailAddress" value="fake@gmail.com">
          <input type="hidden" name="password" value="fake">
            <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="companyUrl" value="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="tenancyName" value="Asset_Management">

            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form" action="/Account/Login?returnUrl=/Application" name="companyLoginForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" name="usernameOrEmailAddress" value="fake@gmail.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="password" value="fake">
            <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="companyUrl" value="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="tenancyName" value="Associates">

            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase">Log in</button>
                </div>
               </div>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form" action="/Account/Login?returnUrl=/Application" name="companyLoginForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<input type="hidden" name="usernameOrEmailAddress" value="fake@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="fake">
            <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="companyUrl" value="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="tenancyName" value="ALL">

            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Post method**

```
 [HttpPost]      
    public virtual async Task<JsonResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel, string returnUrl = "", string returnUrlHash = "", bool companyUrl = false)
   {
             CheckModelState();
            // removed for clarity
    }
```

**Question :** Even though I have press the 2nd submit button,it always send the `tenancyName` as first submit button's value.That is `Asset_Management`.Could you tell me why ? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest changing the logic and merging these inputs into 1 <form>

Comment: Because you have invalid html (nested forms). What are you trying to achieve? What is the point of having multiple forms for `LoginViewModel` - you can only submit one.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please see the app's UI. It's a login page.

Comment: Looking at your now-posted UI, I would not make these buttons submit a form at all. Even hyperlinks would work well here.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you put it as a solution ? I couldn't get what you say.Thanks.

Comment: What does `LoginViewModel`  look like?

Comment: @Sampath, You did not have nested forms (the question has now been edited to fix the indentation). Although its still unclear what your trying to achieve here - how are you handling security - you have no password and any one could manipulate your hidden inputs and login?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes,I have removed those security properties. I'm posting my VM. Thanks.

Comment: @NikolaiDante I have updated it.Please see that.Thanks.

Comment: @Sampath, The code you have show will work fine. Its the code you have not shown which is causing the issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Problem is on `tenancyName`.That is the property which changes according to the `foreach` loop.All others are same for any form.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, because you have something in your code that you have not shown us that is causing the problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated all the values now.Please see that.Thanks.

Comment: What is the `model` for the view (.cshtml page) you have there?

Comment: @Sampath, Need a break, but I will create a DotNetFiddle shortly to prove   what you have shown works.

Comment: @DPac I have updated it.Please see that.Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It works.But it always send first `tenancyName` only for any login button click.Thanks.

Comment: @Sampath. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OeTQYe). Click on the first button and it returns the correct tenancy name. Run it again and click on the second button, and again it returns the correct tenancy name. The problem is with code that you have not shown us :)

Comment: Can you share a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Click the link :-) "Minimal Complete Verifiable Example" basically a sln we can spin up on an IDE that recreates the problem or a broken DotNetFiddle.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you think the issue is plain `form` which I have used for the app ? I have put all the code snippets above.Thanks.

Comment: Nope (its something else that's causing the issue). But I suggest you create a partial view (say `_LogIn.cshtml`) for your model - `@model LoginViewModel` and use the HtmlHelpers (`BeginForm()`, `HiddenFor()` etc to generate your controls (just add `new { id = "" }` so you do not create invalid html) and then in the main view - `@foreach (var item in Model) { @Html.RenderPartial("_LogIn", item) }`

Comment: Having said that, there is something very odd about what your are doing here. Apart from the massive security issues you have (any user can see all your user names and passwords and login and hack your app), its hard to understand what your trying to achieve. Your should have a page with 3 links, and clicking on the appropriate link redirects to a single login form where the user enters their credentials based on the tenancy name you supplied via the link.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Business scenario is this : `Step 1 :` user can enter his email and password on the first page. `Step 2 :` Then go to the server and brings the above mentioned page only if that user is having multiple tenants (companies) with the same email and PW. `Step 3 :` Then from the above page where user can select his company page which he wants to log in at that time. Step 4 : If he's having only 1 company then no need to show the above page. Directly go to the app.So you can see that the scenario is quite complex no ?

Comment: Then your page need only include links (the user is already logged in). All you need is to to generate links that displays each tenancy name and redirects them to the appropriate page (which I assume is your `companyUrl` property). Its hard to understand why your wanting the user to login for a second time.

Comment: Alternatively, if the user has multiple tenancies, why not just display radio buttons for each tenancy in the original login page so that when the user  logs in, you redirect to the appropriate page based on the value of the selected button.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope,First time user not logged in.Just get the tenants details according to the credentials.By using the above page where user logged into the app according to the company where user selects.

Comment: So anyone can navigate to this page, view the page source and see the user name and password for each tenancy which you have included in the hidden fields. You need to rethink what your doing :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope,This page only shows for the right credentials entered user and he must have permissions to logged in multiple companies (tenants). But I would like know whether any other method is there to send model's data without using hidden data ? Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Here I cannot do a model binding.

Comment: We are getting a bit off track here. The code you have shown works (In addition to the DotNetFiddle, I have copied it into a test project and it returns the correct `TenantName`, so its other code your have not shown that is the issue. There is nothing more I can do to help.

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK sure.Thanks a lot for the support.This is my KARMA :(

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated my post above.I have found out a `Js` file which is supporting the `submit` button's functionality.I think the problem is on it.Could you check that too ? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, thats the problem - `var $loginForm = $('.login-form');` followed by `data: $loginForm.serialize()` is going to submit only the first form in your collection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you have any idea to how to sort it out ? B'cos I have to use that `js` file due to this is an SPA app.Thanks.

Comment: Can you modify the file at all - if so you simply need to handle the buttons `.click()` event and get the associated form and then serialize it and sunmit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can I have a code snippet or useful link for how to do this ? Thanks,

Comment: `$('.btn-success').click(function() { var form = $(this).closest('.login-form');` and then in your ajax - `data: form.serialize(),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot friend.It works :) Can you put your help as an answer.Then I can close this thread.Thanks again :)

Comment: Will do, but in a couple of hours :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK sure no problem.I'll treat at that time :D .Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the script.

```
var $loginForm = $('.login-form');
```

is a collection of all your forms, but

```
data: $loginForm.serialize(),
```

will only serialize the first one, so you always posting the vales of the first form. Modify the script to handle the buttons `.click()` event and get its associated form

```
$('.btn-success').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // if you makes the button type="button" this is not required
    var form = $(this).closest('.login-form');
    if (!form.valid()) {
        return;
    }
    abp.ui.setBusy(
        null,
        abp.ajax({
            contentType: app.consts.contentTypes.formUrlencoded,
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize()
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even have `<form>` and `<button>` at all?
Why not create links in your foreach loop, something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login for " + tenant.Name, "LoginAction", new {Id=tenant.Id})
```

You can style these links all blue and pretty as you like using CSS afterwards.

Update1, you can pass parameters to your controller using the anonymous object. Do you see how I am passing Id? Your Action will need to accept id, see this answer: [passing multiple parameters in @html.actionlink()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890766/passing-multiple-parameters-in-html-actionlink)

Update2, passing username and password like this is very bad practice. You are exposing secure credentials to the view. You should forward the user to the login page with username + password input boxes where the user will login.

Comment: How can I send other form properties then? Other hidden filed values ?