# Conditionally render something in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for the equivalent of Reacts Higher Order Components in ASP.NET MVC 5.

So I have a load of controls which should be conditionally rendered based on security privileges. If the user has a specific privilege then they should see the control. If not then the control is hidden.

If I did this in the viewModel I'd need to pollute my view model builders with Security Privileges checks so I was hoping to do it in some kind of control.

I was hoping for something like:

```
@Html.PermissionCheck(new Privilege[ SecurityPrivilege.CanEdit ]) {
    <input type="button" value="Edit" />
}
```

In this way my permissions check code is all in one place and I have access to the user object with no need to pass it into all my model builders.

I've seen various control examples including this: [ASP.NET MVC Html Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173128/asp-net-mvc-html-helper)

The problem with the above is it seems great for wrapping up my control in a standard surround. Less so at conditionally rendering it.

Not sure how to get partial views to accept a group of content.

Comment: I assume my answer didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

A `HtmlHelper` extension would still work for you:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static bool PermissionCheck(this HtmlHelper helper, Privilege[] privs)
    {
       ...
       return true/false;
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@if(Html.PermissionCheck(new Privilege[ SecurityPrivilege.CanEdit ]))
{
    <input type="button" value="Edit" />
}
```

Conditionally rendering being based off the `@if()` syntax provided by the [Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1) engine.

The linked example is over complicating it. That is used for content that needs to be wrapped. All your looking for is to return a simple `bool`.